# Vue Js - Why do changes to data not update the view in some cases

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

With the code below, if you click the add you can see in the console that the value changes, but the view is not updated.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dateValue: new Date(2017,0,1),    
  },
  methods: {
    addOne: function () {     
      this.dateValue.setDate(this.dateValue.getDate() + 1);    
      console.log('new date',this.dateValue);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    Date Value : {{ dateValue }}<br />
    
    <button v-on:click="addOne">Add One</button> <br />
</div>
```

If I introduce simple integer value and display it next to the date, it will work properly and it causes the date value to update properly as well.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dateValue: new Date(2017,0,1), 
    intValue: 0
  },
  methods: {
    addOne: function () {     
      this.dateValue.setDate(this.dateValue.getDate() + 1);  
      this.intValue++;
      
      console.log('new date',this.dateValue);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    Date Value : {{ dateValue }}   Int Value : {{ intValue }}<br />
    
    <button v-on:click="addOne">Add One</button> <br />
</div>
```

I have fussed with setting the date in various ways and I just don't understand what is going on here.  Somehow the mutation of the date isn't being detected. I am hopeful that someone can shed some light on this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This line...

```
this.dateValue.setDate(this.dateValue.getDate() + 1);
```

... changes the 'contents' of a Date object stored in `this.dateValue`, but not the object (the reference) itself. Essentially, `this.dateValue` has the same value as before, so no change is detected by the corresponding mechanism, and no view update is triggered. Now compare with this snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    dateValue: new Date(2017,0,1),    
  },
  methods: {
    addOne: function () {     
      this.dateValue = new Date(
        this.dateValue.setDate(this.dateValue.getDate() + 1)
      );
      console.log('new date',this.dateValue);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    Date Value : {{ dateValue }}<br />
    
    <button v-on:click="addOne">Add One</button> <br />
</div>
```

As new Date object is created at each call of `addOne()`, the change *is* detected, and the corresponding view is updated.

---

Why does your second snippet work, you might ask? Again, the answer is about change detection. As `intValue` value is changed, it's enough to trigger re-render of the whole component (app instance, in this particular case).

And yes, while building a new Virtual DOM for the changed state, VueJS retrieves values of all the properties - not just the changed ones. It's the difference between new and old V-DOMs that will be applied to the real DOM.

Comment: This helped me understand my issue as well.  I was updating an array via a function. I was assigning a new value to the array location.  Once I switched it to an array.splice the change was reflected in my view.  Thank you.